# How to make a Jenkins pipeline run on a specific agent label but never on some others (*) by mask?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

Is it enough "*" for the mask to work here?

I do like this:

```
pipeline {   
    agent { label "label10&&!static&&!label10-43538*" }
    options {
        timeout(time: 10, unit: 'MINUTES')
        timestamps()
    }
}
```

But periodically the agents starting with label10-43538* (e.g. label10-43538-457) still try to execute the code.
While agents label10-43538* are part of label label10.

p.s. Label label10 has another agents that I just need to use.